# Monitoring file system changes and logging to file

Tags: windows, powershell, filesystemwatcher

My actual goal is to monitor a folder for files being created and in which order they are created. Maybe there is a better tool than powershell. If so please let me know.

I took and tailored the second script [here](https://powershell.one/tricks/filesystem/filesystemwatcher) to monitor file system changes.

It uses System.IO.FileSystemWatcher to monitor the file system and fire events for certain changes in a folder.

I need to write the result to a file. First try was to pipe to Out-File. As we have tons of changes each and every second performance was very bad.

Then I took StreamWriter and and WriteLine'd the events. Performance is better know but still not perfect.

Would it make sense to use the asnchronous version of WriteLine? Or is there a even better way?

```
# specify the path to the folder you want to monitor:
$Path = "D:\Transfer\"

# specify whether you want to monitor subfolders as well:
$IncludeSubfolders = $true

# specify the file or folder properties you want to monitor:
$AttributeFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]::FileName

try
{
  $watcher = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileSystemWatcher -Property @{
    Path = $Path
    IncludeSubdirectories = $IncludeSubfolders
    NotifyFilter = $AttributeFilter
  }

  # define the code that should execute when a change occurs:
  $action = {
    # the code is receiving this to work with:
    
    # change type information:
    $details = $event.SourceEventArgs
    $FullPath = $details.FullPath
    $OldFullPath = $details.OldFullPath
    
    # type of change:
    $ChangeType = $details.ChangeType
    
    # when the change occured:
    $Timestamp = ($event.TimeGenerated).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffffZ")
    $TimestampNow = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffffZ")
    
    # now you can define some action to take based on the
    # details about the change event:
    
    # you can also execute code based on change type here:
    switch ($ChangeType)
    {
      "Created"  { $text = "{0}`t{1}`t{2}`t{3}" -f $TimestampNow, $Timestamp, $ChangeType, $FullPath }
      "Deleted"  { $text = "{0}`t{1}`t{2}`t{3}" -f $TimestampNow, $Timestamp, $ChangeType, $FullPath }
      "Renamed"  { $text = "{0}`t{1}`t{2}`t{3}`t{4}" -f $TimestampNow, $Timestamp, $ChangeType, $FullPath, $OldFullPath }
      "Error"  { $text = "{0}`t`t{1}" -f $TimestampNow, $ChangeType }
    }

    $global:SW.WriteLine($text)
    $global:SW.Flush()
  }

  # subscribe your event handler to all event types that are
  # important to you. Do this as a scriptblock so all returned
  # event handlers can be easily stored in $handlers:
  $handlers = . {
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Created  -Action $action 
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Deleted  -Action $action 
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Renamed  -Action $action 
  }

  # monitoring starts now:
  $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

  Write-Warning "Watching for changes to $Path"

  # since the FileSystemWatcher is no longer blocking PowerShell
  # we need a way to pause PowerShell while being responsive to
  # incoming events. Use an endless loop to keep PowerShell busy:
  do
  {
    # Wait-Event waits for a second and stays responsive to events
    # Start-Sleep in contrast would NOT work and ignore incoming events
    Wait-Event -Timeout 1
  } while ($true)
}
finally
{
  # this gets executed when user presses CTRL+C:
  
  # stop monitoring
  $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
  
  # remove the event handlers
  $handlers | ForEach-Object {
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $_.Name
  }
  
  # event handlers are technically implemented as a special kind
  # of background job, so remove the jobs now:
  $handlers | Remove-Job
  
  # properly dispose the FileSystemWatcher:
  $watcher.Dispose()
  
  $global:SW.Close()

  Write-Warning "Event Handler disabled, monitoring ends."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I suggest calling [`Register-ObjectEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent) *without* an `-Action` argument, and instead letting PowerShell *queue* the events internally.
- You can then process each event in the queue sequentially with the [`Wait-Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/wait-event) cmdlet, directly in a loop.

I'm assuming that this improves performance, because there is the no need to invoke a script block hosted in a dynamic module that must be called for each event (which is what `-Action` does).

General caveats:

- The .NET [`System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileSystemWatcher) API itself can miss events, because it is notified of events via a buffer of fixed size; the buffer size can be increased, however. See the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher#remarks) section for more information.
- On the PowerShell side, I don't think there's a queue size limit, so you can at least hypothetically run out of memory if you don't consume the queue fast enough.
- Events do seem to be reported by PowerShell in chronological order, but note the following:

  - What is a single file operation from the user's perspective may result in *multiple* events, notably when files are *moved* - again, see the "Remarks" link above.

    - Update: You report that the two events that are reported in your case for a move - `Created` and `Deleted` - are unexpectedly *out of chronological order*: sensibly, creating the file in the new location happens before deleting it from the old location, as reflected in their event timestamps, but you received the `Deleted` event first.
  - If you use *wildcards* to delete files (e.g. `Remove-Item *`), the files aren't necessarily deleted in *alphabetical* order, so the order of deletion events doesn't reflect alphabetical order either.

The following adaptation of your code demonstrates this technique. Note that what is written to the log file for each event is simplified in the interest of brevity:

```bash
$Path = "/Users/mklement/Desktop/pg/tf"
$logFile = '/Users/mklement/Desktop/pg/o.txt' # Be sure to use a FULL PATH.

# specify whether you want to monitor subfolders as well:
$IncludeSubfolders = $true

# specify the file or folder properties you want to monitor:
$AttributeFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]::FileName

try
{
  $watcher = [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher] @{
    Path = $Path
    IncludeSubdirectories = $IncludeSubfolders
    NotifyFilter = $AttributeFilter
  }

  # Subscribe your event handler to all event types that are
  # important to you.
  # Note: 
  #  * The event names also serve as the -SourceIdentifier values, for
  #    later unregistering with Unregister-Event.
  #  * Without -Action, Register-ObjectEvent produces NO output.
  $eventNames = 'Created', 'Deleted', 'Renamed'
  $eventNames | ForEach-Object {
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName $_ -SourceIdentifier $_
  }

  # monitoring starts now:
  $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

  Write-Warning "Watching for changes to $Path"

  # Create the stream writer for the log file.
  $sw = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $logFile

  # Process events one by one, as they arrive, indefinitely.
  # Ctrl-C is needed to exit.
  while ($true) {
    # Synchronously wait for the next event / process the next queued one.
    # Note: *Any* event is waited for here, so the assumption is that
    #       your session is only subscribed to file system-watcher events.
    #       If necessary, you could filter out unrelated ones.
    $evt = Wait-Event
    $evt | Remove-Event # Events must be removed manually from the queue.
    # Write the event details to the log file...
    $sw.WriteLine(
      $evt.SourceEventArgs.psobject.Properties.Value -join "`t"
    )
    # ... and flush it asynchronously.
    $sw.FlushAsync()
  }

}
finally
{
  # This gets executed when user presses CTRL+C:

  # Close the log file.
  $sw.Close()

  # Unregister the event subscriptions.
  $eventNames | ForEach-Object { Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $_ }

  # properly dispose of the FileSystemWatcher:
  $watcher.Dispose()
  
  Write-Warning "Event Handler disabled, monitoring ends."
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! Are the items in this queue in chronological order? Is it possible to miss some events?

Comment: Thank you for you helpful update!

I read that I can tell from the ChangeType (Error) that I missed some events.

As far as I understand from my tests (with my code and your code) events are in chronological order MOST OF THE TIME.

From time to time I get two events where the first one has a TimeGenerated after the second one.

That was the reason why I thought I had performance issues. Don't really understand that yet.

Comment: @stackedyellowangel, good to know that they're _not_ guaranteed to be in order (in my informal tests, I never saw that). I don't know what causes that; perhaps it is related to the event handlers getting called from different threads. I'm confused that  the `.ChangeType` event-argument property would report an _error_, given that no such value is part of the [`System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes) enum, and you seemingly need to subscribe to a _separate event_ to be notified of errors.

Comment: @stackedyellowangel, the file-system watcher has a [`.SynchronizingObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.synchronizingobjec) property, which _may_ help with the out-of-order issue - I'm out of my depth here. It is also sounds like it's nontrivial to implement.

Comment: It seems that the events are in chronological order with one exception: When you move a file to another folder the action is split up into two actions: one copy and one delete. The delete is reported first and the copy is reported second which made me wonder. But when I check the TimeGenerated I can see that the copy happend first and the delete second. This makes sense to me. So the overall problem was that I didn't know about this behavior and both solutions seem to work perfectly. So I think you got the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @stackedyellowangel - I've updated the answer to note that. I'm still curious as to how you were able to match errors via `.ChangeType`.

Comment: Like this: `    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName Error -Action $actionError` the function is called from time to time.

Comment: That makes sense, @stackedyellowangel. What confused me was that this call isn't part of the code in your question (only `Created`, `Deleted`, and `Renamed` are registered for).